# pulseaudio - Audio Record Application - Access Denied Error

Tags: audio-recording, pulseaudio

I am working on pulseaudio for recording sound and I faced with the "Access Denied" error.

First of all, I am working in Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
I am trying to connect to server with following part of code :

```
    _s              = NULL;
    int32_t err    = -1;
    _ss.format      = PA_SAMPLE_S16LE;
    _ss.rate        = 44100;
    _ss.channels    = 2;

    _s = pa_simple_new(NULL, "Recorder", PA_STREAM_RECORD, NULL, "record", &_ss, NULL, NULL, &err);
```

**pa_simple_new** not return null, so I assume that, this part is not wrong.

But in another part of code, I am trying to read data from server like following :

```
            int32_t err = -1;
            int8_t buff[ ( CIRC_DATA_SIZE ) ] = { 0x00 };
            if ( pa_simple_read(_s, &buff, ( CIRC_DATA_SIZE ), &err ) > 0 )
            {
                _ReadBuff->add_to_buffer(buff, ( CIRC_DATA_SIZE ) );

            }else { DEBUG_MSG("Unable to read from audio device, %s\n", pa_strerror(err));  }
```

In the output of application, I saw following statement :
**Unable to read from audio device, Access denied**

Then I set the **PULSE_COOKIE** environment variable like this :

```
export PULSE_COOKIE=/home/sbahadirarslan/.config/pulse/cookie
```

By the way, cookie file is really exist in /home/sbahadirarslan/.config/pulse directory.

After this arrangement, application give me same error log.
Then I set **PULSE_SERVER** environment variable like this :

```
export PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native
```

But after this change, application gave me the same error.
So Are these changes wrong or Do I have to make other changes ?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

try it:
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio